# How to insert object of arrays into an object- javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the data I'm trying to create for my POST method:

```
{
    "main": {
        "b": [{
            "field": "ss",
            "value": "30",
            "operator": "LT"
        }],
        "a": [{
                "field": "tttt",
                "value": "s",
                "operator": "IN"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The below fiddle has the code that I use to get this JSON structure.

http://jsfiddle.net/dz4cq0sj/14/

While looping through an array, it takes only the last object that was created and does not push any previous objects, like in this case I have:

`obj.criteria[a,b] //where`a`and`b`are objects`, so it takes only the `b` objects details.

```
 {
        "main": {
            "b": [{
                "field": "ss",
                "value": "30",
                "operator": "LT"
            }],
            "a": []
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Use `array.push.apply(object)`;

Comment: It's a good idea to post your code in the question body as a runnable snippet. External links can change over time.

Comment: @SookieSingh: nothing go inserted in any of the objects when I tried .apply()